# textContent and innerHTML not changing the DOM

Tags: javascript, html

Good morning,

I'm hoping someone can help me with this seemingly simple question.  I can't figure out why my `textContent` or `innerHTML` won't update my DOM. It shows in my console that it has changed, but for some reason that escapes me I can't figure out why the DOM isn't changing.  Any help is appreciated!

I have the following code

```js
        function updateText() {

            document.querySelectorAll('.userRoleStyle').forEach(function (e) {

                var grabtext = e.textContent || e.innerHTML;

                if (grabtext === 'SUPER') {

                    grabtext = 'Super User';

                }
                console.log(grabtext);
            })
        };
```

```css
    table td {
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Email address</th>
                <th>User Role</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>TEST1</td>
                <td>test@test.com</td>
                <td class="userRoleStyle">ADMINISTRATOR</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" onclick="updateText();">Test</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="userList">
                <td>TEST2</td>
                <td>test@test.com</td>
                <td class="userRoleStyle">ADMINISTRATOR</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" onclick="updateText();">Test</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="userList">
                <td>TEST3</td>
                <td>test@test.com</td>
                <td class="userRoleStyle">SUPER</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" onclick="updateText();">Test</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: How are you checking? If you're using "View Source", that isn't showing you the DOM, that's showing you the HTML delivered from the server. To actually check the DOM, use the "Elements" panel in your browser's devtools (in most browsers, you can right-click and choose "Inspect element").

Comment: Because nowhere in your code are you trying to update it.

Comment: Nothing in your quoted code *changes* the DOM, so....?

Comment: I thought by using the if statement - it would change the page content?

Comment: That's because you just changing the variable 'grabtext', instead you should update 'e.innerHTML' or 'e.textContent'.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the snippet.

You were not assigning the `Super User` value to e.textContent inside `if` condition

```js
function updateText() {

            document.querySelectorAll('.userRoleStyle').forEach(function (e) {
           
                var grabtext = e.textContent || e.innerHTML;

                if (grabtext === 'SUPER') {

                    e.textContent = 'Super User';

                }
            })
        };
```

```css
table td {
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Email address</th>
                <th>User Role</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>TEST1</td>
                <td>test@test.com</td>
                <td class="userRoleStyle">ADMINISTRATOR</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" onclick="updateText();">Test</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="userList">
                <td>TEST2</td>
                <td>test@test.com</td>
                <td class="userRoleStyle">ADMINISTRATOR</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" onclick="updateText();">Test</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="userList">
                <td>TEST3</td>
                <td>test@test.com</td>
                <td class="userRoleStyle">SUPER</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" onclick="updateText();">Test</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for this, appreciate the help!

Comment: @Xoog: Note that if you use the code above, a browser that doesn't support `textContent` (IE8, IE9-IE11 in "compatibility" mode...) won't see the change.

Answer (score 2):

`innerHTML` and `textContent` are basically setters and getters. Getting their reference in a variable and setting value to that reference will not invoke the setter.

You need to set value directly to them

```
e.textContent ? 
 ( e.textContent == 'SUPER' ? (e.textContent = 'Super User') : "" ) : 
 ( e.innerHTML == 'SUPER' ? (e.innerHTML = 'Super User') : "" )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I see where I was going wrong now!

Comment: Sure, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in your code *changes* what's in the DOM. Assigning to your `grabText` variable just changes the value of that variable, not the element you got the text from.

To do that, you'd havE to assign back to `textContent`/`innerHTML`.

Separately: `innerHTML` is very different from `textContent`. If you're going to feature-detect, use `textContent` and fall back to `innerText`, not `innerHTML`¹. When feature-detecting this, don't just use `||`, it can pick the wrong one if the element's text is blank. Instead, look to see if the element has a property with the desired name. You only need to do it once and remember it.

```
var textPropName = "textContent" in document.createElement("div") ? "textContent" : "innerText";

function updateText() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.userRoleStyle').forEach(function(e) {
    if (e[textPropName] === 'SUPER') {
      e[textPropName] = 'Super User';
    }
  })
}
```

```js
var textPropName = "textContent" in document.createElement("div") ? "textContent" : "innerText";

function updateText() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.userRoleStyle').forEach(function(e) {
    if (e[textPropName] === 'SUPER') {
      e[textPropName] = 'Super User';
    }
  })
}
```

```css
table td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email address</th>
        <th>User Role</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST1</td>
        <td>test@test.com</td>
        <td class="userRoleStyle">ADMINISTRATOR</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" onclick="updateText();">Test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="userList">
        <td>TEST2</td>
        <td>test@test.com</td>
        <td class="userRoleStyle">ADMINISTRATOR</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" onclick="updateText();">Test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="userList">
        <td>TEST3</td>
        <td>test@test.com</td>
        <td class="userRoleStyle">SUPER</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" onclick="updateText();">Test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

---

Side note: You don't put `;` after function *declarations*. It's a statement terminator; declarations aren't statements. You'd have one after an assignment statement with a function expression, but not after a declaration. (It's harmless, though.)

---

¹ [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) and [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) are also different from one another, but the differences don't matter in your case.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up for me, appreciate the help!